# Insert large Dataframe into Oracle DB using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cx-oracle

I need to insert dataframe having 0.5 million rows quickly into Oracle DB table Table has columns with various datatypes

DB Table Info

```
CL_SEQ             NUMBER
CL_TMID            VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
CL_CLIENT_ID       VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
CL_PAN             VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
CL_CLI_STATUS      CHAR(1 BYTE)
CL_PAN_STATUS      CHAR(2 BYTE)
CL_ACTION_TYPE     VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
CL_CREATED_DATE    DATE
CL_CREATED_BY      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
CL_MODIFIED_DATE   DATE
CL_MODIFIED_BY     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
```

Initially I am trying to insert just a single row but unable to insert

MY Dataframe Info

```
    cx_oracle version 8.2.1
connection successful
    CL_SEQ  CL_TMID CL_CLIENT_ID      CL_PAN CL_CLI_STATUS CL_PAN_STATUS  CL_ACTION_TYPE   CL_CREATED_DATE CL_CREATED_BY  CL_MODIFIED_DATE CL_MODIFIED_BY
0  3793375       21      MEN0008  ARJPP6330Q             A            V                0  09/06/2019 14:23        SYSTEM  09/09/2019 11:28         SYSTEM
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>        
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   CL_SEQ            1 non-null      int64 
 1   CL_TMID           1 non-null      int64 
 2   CL_CLIENT_ID      1 non-null      object
 3   CL_PAN            1 non-null      object
 4   CL_CLI_STATUS     1 non-null      object
 5   CL_PAN_STATUS     1 non-null      object
 6   CL_ACTION_TYPE    1 non-null      int64
 7   CL_CREATED_DATE   1 non-null      object
 8   CL_CREATED_BY     1 non-null      object
 9   CL_MODIFIED_DATE  1 non-null      object
 10  CL_MODIFIED_BY    1 non-null      object
dtypes: int64(3), object(8)
memory usage: 216.0+ bytes
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\insertfutclient.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO UCIDBA.FUT_CLIENT_LIST_COPY VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11)",rows)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Need help as I am stuck it in for quite sometime now.

Code :

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import pandas as pd

ip = '192.168.213.151'
port = 1515
SID = 'devnc12c'
print("cx_oracle version",cx_Oracle.version)
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('NCSWEB', 'Ncvvv##234', dsn_tns)
cursor = connection.cursor()
print("connection successful")
fileName='C:\\Users\\ncdex1124\Desktop\\New folder\\file10.csv'
data_df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
print(data_df)
print(data_df.info())
rows = [tuple(x) for x in data_df.values]
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO UCIDBA.FUT_CLIENT_LIST_COPY VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11)",rows)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Use the appropriate NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting or TO_DATE().  Or use the batch errors mode of `executemany()` to help  with bogus rows